# Specifying space character in Youtube HTTP request

Tags: java, http, youtube, youtube-data-api

Here is my code to make a HTTP data request to Youtube:

```
 String apiKey =MY_KEY;
//variable input contains search keyword
    String query = "";
    if(input.contains(" "))
        query = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+input.replace(" ","+")+"&type=video&videoCaption=closedCaption&key="+apiKey;
    else
        query = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+input+"&type=video&videoCaption=closedCaption&key="+apiKey;
    try {
        response = makeHTTPRequest.sendGet(query);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Youtube results : "+response);
```

So I am trying to replace space character in a keyword such as **Electronics City** with **+** sign. Is this wrong? What changes should be make to get search results only for *electronics city* and not for just *electronics* or *city*?

Currently I getting search results for Electronics City, and electronics as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [url encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) certain characters. Luckily, there is [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) which you could use by doing something like,

```
try {
    String query = String.format("https://www.googleapis.com/" //
                + "youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%s&type=video&" //
                + "videoCaption=closedCaption&key=%s", URLEncoder.encode( //
            input, "UTF-8"), URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "UTF-8"));
    response = makeHTTPRequest.sendGet(query);
    System.out.printf("Youtube results : %s%n", response);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```